# Passing flags to a command inside an alias

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, zsh

I have created an alias for `ls` in order to let it print out a format that I like. I have defined the following alias to do this:

`alias ls="ls -lo --color=always | awk '{if (NR != 1) {print \$8,\$5,\$6,\$7}}' | column -t"`

I am satisfied with the result of my alias, but I also want to be able to pass other flags to the ls command inside the alias. For example, if I now run `ls -a`, it logically adds the `-a` flag to the `column` command, since it is the last command in the pipeline defined in the alias, but it is actually intended for the ls command. Is there any way to bring this flag all the way forward to the ls command inside the alias?

Comment: [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618)

Comment: As is almost always the case when you have trouble getting an alias to do what you want, the answer is "use a function instead". Functions can control what happens to their arguments, aliases cannot.

Comment: ^^^ Ditto, although "functions can control what happens to their arguments, aliases cannot" is not entirely right. In the first place in Bash or Zsh there is *no concept of arguments of an alias*. An alias replaces one *string* with another *string*, it's *purely textual* operation, there is no deeper logic available. A string after an alias is not "arguments", it's just a tail that stays intact during the replacement. Only *after* the alias is expanded the result and the tail may form a command so (some) arguments come from the tail. When the alias does its job there are only strings.